# blender crashing in arch linux

Tags: error, linux

I have installed Blender 2.83 in my arch Linux installation and it crashes. I downloaded it from the repo then also tried from the official site. It still fails.. help needed

```
# Blender 2.83.0, Commit date: 2020-06-03 14:38, Hash 211b6c29f771

# backtrace
blender(BLI_system_backtrace+0x34) [0x55806be25ba4]
blender(+0xd03e7d) [0x558069b6ee7d]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x3c3e0) [0x7fa86daaa3e0]
blender(GPU_draw_list_command_add+0x57) [0x55806bcf68f7]
blender(+0x10b9355) [0x558069f24355]
blender(+0x10bac94) [0x558069f25c94]
blender(+0x10e5916) [0x558069f50916]
blender(+0x10b22f3) [0x558069f1d2f3]
blender(DRW_draw_render_loop_ex+0x2c7) [0x558069f1d5f7]
blender(view3d_main_region_draw+0x98) [0x55806a5d3dd8]
blender(ED_region_do_draw+0x8a1) [0x55806a1a1e61]
blender(wm_draw_update+0x4d5) [0x558069e30a75]
blender(WM_main+0x34) [0x558069e2ea34]
blender(main+0x36b) [0x558069b3d31b]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf2) [0x7fa86da95002]
blender(_start+0x2e) [0x558069b6b0fe]
```

Note: My arch installation is also new.

Answer (score 1):

**< My Problem >**

Blender freezes whole UI of operating system.

**< Solution >**

**I am not responsible if this damage your OS or any other thing**

I have Intel UHD 630 GPU, I switched from Intel to MODESETTING driver, this fixed my issue, Try it IF it works for you , share with other people. :)

*To enable MODESETTING you have to  edit /etc/mkinitcpio.conf
Put MODULES=(... i915 ...)  below  MODULES=""
*Delete this package from system xf86-video-intel.
*Then reboot system.

**< About System >**

CPU: Intel core i5-8400
Ram: 8gb
Gpu : Intel UHD 630
Os: EndeavourOS

**< How to revert these changes? >**

*Install this package system xf86-video-intel.
*You have to edit /etc/mkinitcpio.conf
remove  MODULES=(... i915 ...)  below  MODULES=""

**< Reference >**
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_mode_setting#Early_KMS_start

Comment: Don't post solutions that may damage users' OS or hardware. That's the best way to avoid trouble later.